# How do I limit a set within my domain object

Tags: java, hibernate

The code retrieves a object with ( old style ) hibernate :

```
Session session = super.getSession();
Student  results = (Student) session.get(Student.class, id);
```

The Student object has , within it, a set of the kid's achievements.

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="edu.texas.Student" table="STUDENT" >
    <property name="createUser" type="string">
        <column name="CREATE_USER" length="25" />
    </property>

    <set name="achievements" inverse="true" lazy="true" table="ACHIEVEMENTS" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="ACHIEVEMENT_ID" length="25" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="edu.texas.Achievements" />
    </set>
```

I would like the set of Achievements to be limited by a date range ( for example, only those from this year, instead of the entire career of the kid ).

I started with using criteria on the Set's objects, but Criteria wants to return a list.

The list, in this case, is WITHIN my Student object.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Student.class)
                     .createAlias("achievements", "a")
                     .add( Restrictions.between("a.createTs", startDate, endDate ) );
results = (Student) crit.uniqueResult();
```

Comment: That's because you're creating a `Student` entity with your `createCriteria` expression

Comment: @Dan So I should create the criteria on `Achievements` , but how do I use that in my `session.get ()` ?

Comment: Is this a uni or bi directional relationship?  If it's bi-directional then you can just switch what you've got listed above `Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Achievent.class)
                     .createAlias("students", "s")...`